# Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for `spanish'

Tags: hyphenation, languages, polyglossia

The initial error:

How to solve this error on macOS?

`` Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for `spanish' (polyglossia)                I will use \language=\l@nohyphenation instead on i nput line 13. ``

According with comments,I only needed to install Spanish, `hyphen-spanish`,support and in R it works with the follow code:

`tinytex::tlmgr_install("hyphen-spanish")`

Bye

Comment: you need to install spanish support and rebuild the formats (which is rather strange) if you use texlive check `tlmgr info hyphen-spanish` to see if it is installed

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will study about it, but  really I create my pdf_output through rstudio, and the warning that I have referred is popping up in the R markdown console. I mean i don't know  about * tlmgr info hyphen-spanish, neither how and where i need to install it. ¿Can you help me with that?.

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle, your answer was so helpful, last night I was reading about it, and now my output_pdf is correct and doesn't pop any waring. In fact, *hyphen-spanish was not installed. 

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to install spanish support and rebuild the formats (which is rather strange, as this would normally be included by default when you first installed tex). If you use texlive check

```
tlmgr info hyphen-spanish
```

to see if it is installed

and

```
tlmgr install  hyphen-spanish
```

to install it if needed.